# podman.sock: connect: no such file or directory when using podman pull image

Tags: podman

I am install podman in MacOS Catalina 10.15.7:

```
~/source/dabai/microservice/soa-illidan-hub on  feature/cardrobot ⌚ 13:01:36
$ brew install podman

==> Downloading https://mirrors.aliyun.com/homebrew/homebrew-bottles/bottles/podman-2.1.1.catalina.bottle.tar.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring podman-2.1.1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/podman/2.1.1: 143 files, 37.1MB
(base)
```

but when I am using this command to pull image:

```
~/source/dabai/microservice/soa-illidan-hub on  feature/cardrobot ⌚ 13:06:50
$ podman pull ubuntu
Error: Get "http://d/v2.0.0/libpod../../../_ping": dial unix ///var/folders/sr/16lcx_p11rg0ntdgs673s6z00000gn/T/run--1/podman/podman.sock: connect: no such file or directory
(base)
```

I am searching from internet and seems like a bug? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: you're not alone, same thing here. Here's my uname if that helps whoever is debugging it: `Darwin redacted 20.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.2.0: Wed Dec  2 20:39:59 PST 2020; root:xnu-7195.60.75~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Comment: found this github issue: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/4364

Answer (score 4, accepted):

podman doesn't run on mac and windows without a linux helper

https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/master/docs/tutorials/mac_win_client.md